# Docusign restapi download document using envelope id and document id

Tags: vb.net, restsharp, docusignapi

We are having difficulties downloading updated document from docusign for envelope which is completed. We are doing following restapi request and getting data back but not sure how to create document using response.

Restapi request:

```
GET https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/xxxxx/envelopes/xxxxxx-    xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxxxx/documents/1 HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-AU,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-DocuSign-Authentication: { "Username" : "xxxxxxx", "Password" : "xxxxxxxx", "IntegratorKey" : "xxxxxxxxx" }
User-Agent: RestSharp/104.4.0.0
Host: demo.docusign.net
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Can anyone please suggest what needs to be done once we get response back to save it as .pdf. We are using Vb.net platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [DocuSign.eSign.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/) nuget package and make calls to the DocuSign api.

Here is a sample VB.net code to download a document. See full code [here](https://gist.github.com/codingdawg/67bcd002d8fb1b8f2fd7b9c2977e1ec9).

```
Public Class DocuSignApiTest
     Public Sub GetDocumentRecipe()
         Dim envelopeId As String = "<EnvelopeId>"
         Dim accountId As String = Init()
         Dim envApi = New EnvelopesApi()
         Dim docStream = envApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "1")

         ' let's save the document to local file system
         Dim filePath As String = "C:\temp\" + Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".pdf"

         Using stream = File.Create(filePath)
             docStream.CopyTo(stream)
         End Using
     End Sub

     Public Function Init() As String


         Dim username As String = "<Username>"
         Dim password As String = "<Password>"
         Dim integratorKey As String = "<IntegratorKey>"

         ' initialize client for desired environment (for production change to www)
         Dim apiClient As New ApiClient("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi")
         Configuration.[Default].ApiClient = apiClient

         ' configure 'X-DocuSign-Authentication' header
         Dim authHeader As String = "{""Username"":""" + username + """, ""Password"":""" + password + """, ""IntegratorKey"":""" + integratorKey + """}"
         Configuration.[Default].AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader)

         ' we will retrieve this from the login API call
         Dim accountId As String = Nothing

         '''//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         ' STEP 1: LOGIN API        
         '''//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         ' login call is available in the authentication api 
         Dim authApi As New AuthenticationApi()
         Dim loginInfo As LoginInformation = authApi.Login()

         ' parse the first account ID that is returned (user might belong to multiple accounts)
         accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts(0).AccountId

         ' Update ApiClient with the new base url from login call
         apiClient = New ApiClient(loginInfo.LoginAccounts(0).BaseUrl)

         Return accountId
     End Function

 End Class
```